# Arduino Due SAM3X ADC programmable input offset not working

Tags: atmel, sam3x

In the datasheet of the [SAM3X8E](http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATSAM3X8E.aspx) in Section 43.6.9 Page 1327 it clearly states that the SAM3X/A has a programmable offset for ADC input in Single-Ended mode and I believe that the Atmel ASF library also has a function dedicated to configuring analog offset for SAM's ADC (`adc_enable_channel_input_offset`). However the following lines of code did not work:

```
  adc_set_writeprotect(ADC,0);
  adc_enable_anch(ADC);
  adc_disable_channel_differential_input(ADC, ADC_CHANNEL_5);
  adc_set_channel_input_gain(ADC, ADC_CHANNEL_5, ADC_GAINVALUE_2);
  adc_enable_channel_input_offset(ADC, ADC_CHANNEL_5);
  adc_set_writeprotect(ADC,1);
```

Why??

Comment: I have very similar question http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/32062/arduino-due-adc-gain-adjustment-problem but no answer, unfortunately.