# Arduino Due: ADC gain adjustment problem

Tags: programming, arduino-due, analogread, adc, sam3x

I want to increase gain of the ADC channel. To achieve this I'm using `adc_set_channel_input_gain` function from **adc.h**. Here is the entire sketch:

```
const byte aPin = A6;

void setup() {
  analogReadResolution(12);

  // Configure ADC gain
  // Arduino/hardware/arduino/sam/system/libsam/include/adc.h
  adc_channel_num_t ch = (adc_channel_num_t)(g_APinDescription[aPin].ulADCChannelNumber);
  adc_set_channel_input_gain(ADC, ch, ADC_GAINVALUE_3);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Delay for serial stabilization
  Serial.println("Begin.");
  delay(2000);
}

void loop() {
  int analog = analogRead(aPin);
  Serial.println(analog);
  delay(500);
}
```

The problem is that output values are not depending on the gain value.

Comment: The function `adc_set_channel_input_gain()` is not compliant with the basic analog input library which use only `analogReadResolution()` and `analogRead()`. Please read more about `adc_init(ADC...` for the "sam3x".

Comment: @J.Piquard, thank you for help, where can I find documentation?

Comment: Take a look to that Guide: ["Quickstart guide for SAM ADC driver"](http://asf.atmel.com/docs/latest/sam3x/html/sam_adc_quickstart.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution was very simple. We just need to call `adc_enable_anch()` before changing gain or offset of the ADC. I improved my setup and the sketch works as expected now:

```
void setup() {
  analogReadResolution(12);

  // Configure ADC gain
  // Arduino/hardware/arduino/sam/system/libsam/include/adc.h
  adc_channel_num_t ch = (adc_channel_num_t)(g_APinDescription[aPin].ulADCChannelNumber);
  adc_enable_anch(ADC); 
  adc_set_channel_input_gain(ADC, ch, ADC_GAINVALUE_3);

  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Delay for serial stabilization
  Serial.println("Begin.");
  delay(2000);
}
```